# composer update spend much time

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I use Windows 7 operating system. I have a problem when I try to launch command like :

```
php composer.phar update
```

15 minutes to launch update and I have a good internet connection (maybe more !). It happen when I use another internet connections.

What happen ?

Comment: Is all the source reachable. If not you have to use proxy.

Comment: Is Composer itself taking around 15 mins to start up or is it the update which downloads & installs your packages that is taking that 15 mins?

Comment: The update taking 15 mins or more not composer

Answer (score 1):

Composer update can be a slow operation, because it takes a lot of time to resolve dependencies in projects with big dependency graphs. If you open system monitor at some point while composer is updating, you will probably see 100% CPU utilisation on one core at least.

*If you have XDebug enabled, disable it because it degrades composer performance significantly.*

Whenever you have `composer.lock` file and you don't actually want to update your project's dependencies, it is best to use `composer install`, as it will just install versions of libraries defined in `composer.lock` and will be finished a lot faster.

Comment: I have two questions : how to disable XDebug ? I edited php.ini file but I still have the message - Why composer update work very fast when I use linux system ?